# dictionary of lists to tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples, dictionary-comprehension

I am quite sure there must be a more pythonic way to do this rather than the one I used.

So a dictionary of dictionaries of lists ---> dictionary of lists of tuples

Say:

```
ff = {'one': {'aaa': [1, 2, 3], 'bbb': [3, 4, 5]}, 'two': {'ccc': [3, 2, 1]}}
```

to

```
test = {'one': [('aaa', 1, 2, 3), ('bbb', 3, 4, 5)], 'two': [('ccc', 3, 2, 1)]}
```

And this is the solution I found:

```
test = { k:[tuple(itertools.chain(itertools.repeat(ksub,1),(elements for elements in vsub))) for ksub,vsub in v.items()] for k,v in ff.items() }
```

Is there a clearer way to to do this?

Comment: i don't think that 'to' has anything to do with tuples

Comment: yes thank you for the contribution.

Comment: Your current version of question dont have differences in input and output.

Comment: I changed it back. Thanks

Comment: @minitoto: sure it does; the nested dictionary contains keys (strings) and values (lists) that are combined into tuples (containing the key and the contents of the value lists).

Comment: @vishes_shell: oops, that's my mistake, I copied the wrong formatted value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sure it didn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use a list comprehension and concatenation for the nested dict items:

```
{k: [(nk,) + tuple(nv) for nk, nv in v.iteritems()] for k, v in ff.iteritems()}
```

Demo:

```
>>> ff = {'one': {'aaa': [1,2,3], 'bbb':[3,4,5] }, 'two': {'ccc' : [3,2,1] }}
>>> {k: [(nk,) + tuple(nv) for nk, nv in v.iteritems()] for k, v in ff.iteritems()}
{'two': [('ccc', 3, 2, 1)], 'one': [('aaa', 1, 2, 3), ('bbb', 3, 4, 5)]}
```

Comment: @Ivan_nn2: and now that I am clear of the  London tunnels, a working answer.

Comment: Which apparently is the fourth most complicated subway in the world... :) That's exactly the answer I was looking for!